# Did Napoleon introduce driving on the right side because he was left-handed?

Tags: history, road, france, driving

Traffic has almost always been keep-to-the-left since at least the time of Rome until relatively recently.

> Some historians, such as C. Northcote Parkinson, believed that ancient travellers on horseback generally rode on the left side of the road. As more people are right-handed, a horseman would thus be able to hold the reins with his left hand and keep his right hand free—to offer in friendship to passing riders or to defend himself with a sword, if necessary.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-_and_left-hand_traffic#History):

> There is a popular story that Napoleon changed the rule of the road in the European countries he conquered from keep-left to keep-right. Some justifications are symbolic, such as that **Napoleon himself was left- (or right-) handed**, or that Britain, Napoleon's enemy, kept left.

According to an [article on eHow](http://www.ehow.com/about_5475849_usa-drive-right-side-road.html):

> This practice was common throughout medieval Europe, until it was changed by the French. During the French Revolution in a bid to turn absolutely everything on its antithesis, the driving laws were changed to "keep right." Napoleon quickly adopted the right-hand rule as law for two reasons--a display of absolute power in even the minutest of details, **and the singular fact that the emperor was left-handed**-- according to Ed Wright's "A Left Handed History of the World."

Is there any basis for this claim? Did Napoleon forcibly introduce driving on the right side simply because **he** was left-handed (or even because the olde enemy drove on the left)?

Answer (score 11):

I asked a very [similar question yesterday on History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/why-did-people-in-some-countries-start-to-drive-on-the-right) and after reading more about it, I believe the answer is not absolutely clear. In any case, [this article from New Scientist](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qfak8nsMNGIC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) seems to provide the clearest answer I've found so far. Rather than because of being left-handed, Napoleon seems to have been keen on changing centuries-long traditions for the sake of creating a whole new society, the purpose behind the Revolution after all.

> There was an obvious class distinction in France between the left- and right-hand sides of the roads. The aristocrats drove in their carriages up the left hand side of the road, forcing the *citoyens* over onto the right. Come the revolution in 1789, and the declaration of the "rights of man" in 1791, the aristocrats had a natural incentive to keep to the poor side of the road, to avoid drawing attention to themselves [...]. Napoleon established the change more firmly by ordering his military traffic to take the right side of the road.